# Java Drawing a map grid for a game

Tags: java, user-interface, draw

Hey I am trying to make a dungeon crawler and I am stuck on the map generation.  I want there to be random rooms generated but before I can do all of that I have to actually draw the map on the screen. I want the map to be top down and pretty much be a grid that I will later add the floor image to it.  My way of thinking is to create a JFrame and draw a Rectangle2D with paintComponent and a for loop to make a grid of squares.  Is this the right way to go?  And Also how would I get the character to move from square to square with a keyListener?

EDIT: A dungeon crawler is a top-down game where you control one character and move him around a grid.  You kill monsters, get weapons and items they drop, level up, etc. Right now I just want to figure our the best way to print the map on the screen. i am starting with just a grid where the character moves from square to square and hitting the arrow keys. Then I will move on to random map generation!

Comment: You'll want to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), not a KeyListener, if this a Swing application. Can you give more details on your actual problem? For instance, I have no idea what a "dungeon crawler" is. I guess I've lived a sheltered life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to create abstraction level first. Start from array, that contains information about each cell (empty, obstacle, enemy, player, item etc.).

Something like that

```
int[][] a={
  {0,0,0,0,0}, 
  {0,1,0,0,0}, //"1" - obstacle
  {0,0,1,0,0},
  {2,0,1,0,0}, //for example "2" is player
  {0,0,1,0,0}
}
```

Now just draw your rectangles (or images, which actually looks better :) ) using to that map. Usually each cell should be same size, so just draw rectangles with some step.

Comment: So after drawing a map using symbols on the keyboard in a 2D array, I can just replace the symbols with pictured tiles?

Comment: @user1198199, not exactly "replace". There is no need to draw this array (named "a" in my example). You should draw your tiles (or rectangles) ACCORDING to this array.

Comment: I see. So store rectangles of the same size in the 2D array and draw it?  I am also having trouble printing this array out.  I have: `for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){ for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){ System.out.println(a[i][j]);}}`

Comment: However it just prints in a single column

Comment: @user1198199 something like that. Give a try, and then ask if there will be any troubles. Actually, it's better to create new question for each problem IF there is no answer already. Good luck )

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create BufferedImages sized to match your map size, get its Graphics object and draw your map using this object, then disposing it. Then you can easily display it in an ImageIcon held by a JLabel, or in a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method.